# Integral points on affine rational curves over $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, diophantine-equations

Given a rational curve $C:(f_1(t),f_2(t))$, where $f_i(t),i=1,2$ are rational functions with rational coefficients.

**Question:** Is there any criterion(proved or conjectural) for the existence of integral points on such a curve?

Comment: In the range of my knowledge, I suppose this question is very difficult to answer. Intuitively, the integral points must exist on the curve.

Comment: The Integral points constitute an Two-dimensional lattice on the complex plane, so the question can be transformed into this: Are all the rational function cann't intersect with the Intergral Points?

Comment: Conjecturally, if there is no integral Brauer-Manin obstruction then the curve has integral points.

Comment: @FelipeVoloch: Is it possible that finite many computations are suffice to decide whether there is integral Brauer-Manin obstruction or not?

Comment: Only if there is no points, then you can step through the countably many obstructions till you prove that. But you can search for points in parallel with computing the obstructions and find a point if there is one.

Comment: @Felipe Voloch: Is there a low-brow account of the integral Brauer-Manin obstruction which works practically in terms of the rational functions $f_1$ and $f_2$?

Comment: @PeterMueller Not that I know of. If you convert the problem into a unit equation in the standard way, then the Brauer-Manin obstruction can be turned into congruence conditions.